# Cordova: How do you hide the status bar on the splash/launch screen?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to remove the status bar across my app with Cordova. I have tried `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />` but it looks like in iOS7 that does not work. (And iOS6 it left a black gap instead.)

I have since been using the StatusBar plugin and just firing `StatusBar.hide();` at device ready, but this will not hide the status bar on the launch screen. Is there a way to hide the status bar across the entire app in iOS7 and not have to rewrite it each time I do a cordova build? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not the full answer that makes Cordova do it automatically. But I went into my .plist file for the iOS build and added:

```
UIStatusBarHidden = true
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = false
```

This makes it behave the correct way and is not getting overwritten by Cordova when I do a build so it will work for now.

If anyone finds or knows of a better way to enforce these settings, feel free to post it and I will either update this answer or choose yours next time I notice it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

### Status Bar

To remove the status bar in iOS 7 use the following entries in the plist file.

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

In the configuration on XCode the following achieves the same

```
set Status bar is initially hidden = YES
add row: View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't waste your time just do simple at the splash time/launch time status bar hide

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why this gets a downvote. Worked perfectly for me. 1 click and it's done.

Comment: @Timo This solution is the same as setting  `UIStatusBarHidden` to true in plist file. U can find they are synchronous.

Comment: Good to know this is a GUI option. I suggest you edit your answer to remove referring to time wasting.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated:**

We can also inject the info.plist directly from config.xml.

```
<config-file parent="UIStatusBarHidden" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <true />
</config-file>
<config-file parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
     <false />
</config-file>
```

The first config will hide the status bar on the splash/lunch screen. The second config will hide the status bar after the splash/lunch screen.

Comment: Its works for me but I used it like this.
**If you want to edit the config.xml file and inject it as marge. I used this and it works for me.**

`<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="UIStatusBarHidden"><true /></edit-config><edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge"target="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance"><false /></edit-config>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the following:

http://ionicframework.com/tutorials/fullscreen-apps/

First, we need to note this only works on Cordova (recommend v3.3.1) or another native `UIWebView` wrapper. If we use Cordova, we will need to install one plugin:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
```

Then, we will use Ionic's Platform service to listen for the device ready event and remove the status bar:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Platform) {
  Platform.ready(function() {
    // hide the status bar using the StatusBar plugin
    StatusBar.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep, doing that. Just using Backbone instead of Iconic/Angular. The launch screen loads before deviceready, so the status bar only hides after that screen.

Comment: I found this only set the text to white, and the battery still showed

Answer (score -1):

I used it to **remove** the **status bar** from the ios application with Ionic & Angular
**FileName: config.xml**

> step1: add code in XML file
>
> step2: import the plugin and implement it on your js file.

```html
<platform name="ios">

<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="UIStatusBarHidden">
<true />
</edit-config>

<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge"target="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
<false />
</edit-config>

</platform>
```

**for your .js/.ts file**

**Hiding and showing StatuBar**

I used this plugin Link: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

**import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';**

**constructor(
private statusBar: StatusBar
){}**

> this.StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
>
> this.StatusBar.hide();